# recursive Map() passing multiple lists and constants as arguments

Tags: r, function, recursion, arguments, parameter-passing

This is a question that relates to my previous two questions:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996470/how-to-map-a-function-recursively-through-nested-lists-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906958/how-to-combine-rapply-and-mapply-or-how-to-use-mapply-map-recursively), and
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906958/how-to-combine-rapply-and-mapply-or-how-to-use-mapply-map-recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996470/how-to-map-a-function-recursively-through-nested-lists-in-r)
, except now I am asking for more bells and whistles...

So I have multiple nested lists:

```
A = list(list(list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4)),list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))), list(c(4,3,2), c(3,2,1)))
B = list(list(list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4)),list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))), list(c(4,3,2), c(3,2,1)))
```

And I'd like to apply a function recursively to the corresponding lists in `A` and `B`. If the function only takes sublists of `A` and `B` as arguments, according to excellent answers to my previous questions, it can be done like this:

```
recursive  <- function(fun, x, y) {
if(is.atomic(x) && is.atomic(y)) {
    match.fun(fun)(x, y) 
} else  {
    Map(recursive, x, y, MoreArgs=list(fun=fun))
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering how can I add more arguments that are constant across different sublists of `A` and `B`? For instance, my function could be

```
formula = function(sublistA, sublistB, arg1, arg2){return(arg1*sublistA+arg2*sublistB)}
```

I think the recursive function possibly adapted from above might look like

```
recursive  <- function(fun, x, y, a, b) {
if(is.list(a) && is.list(b)){
}...
}
```

And can we make the recursive function flexible regarding the number of structured lists like `x` and `y` and the number of constants (could be matrices, vectors, lists, so long as not included in the recursion) like `a` and `b`?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself... Pretty dumb question itself.

Just write the function to include the constants...